# C# Kendo UI Asp.Net MVC trigger not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a Asp.Net MVC application in which I added some Keno UI (Telerik) components. One of them is the Kendo Combo box, which is working fine ecxept that the change event doesn't fire.

Here is my code in Asp.Net for the Combo Box:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
          .Name("EingangDrop")
          .Placeholder("Eingang durch...")
          .DataTextField("WSText")
          .DataValueField("ID")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { ng_model="Modell.EingangDurch" })
          .Filter("contains")
          .AutoBind(false)
          .MinLength(3)
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetVersand", "UserApi");
              })
              .ServerFiltering(false);
          })
    )
```

This is working fine and the Data Source is set proberly.
BUT now I am having this problem with a jquery function.
I want to change the select via jQuery which is not working.

Here my code for jQuery:

```
// fire change event (this is not working)
$("#EingangDrop").data("kendoComboBox").select(1);
$('#EingangDrop').trigger("change");
```

I am firing a change event as said in the Api, but this still doesn't show. No selection is made.

I think that the problem is related to the DataSource! When I am clicking on the combobox before the jQuery function call and then I am calling the function afterwards then the selection is made. But this only works if I click on the ComboBox before. I belive that it doesn't load the datasource if I don't click on it and then there can not be a selection because the DataSource didn't load at this time.

Comment: Change [autoBind](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-autoBind) to true. If it is set to false data are loaded after you click it - not before.

Comment: Anyway, in your code example I can't see [change](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/events) event binded to ComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a select etc. on your ComboBox, you have to set

```
AutoBind(true)
```

> Setting autoBind to false is useful when multiple widgets are bound to
>   the same data source. Disabling automatic binding ensures that the
>   shared data source does not make more than one request to the remote
>   service.

which should then look like:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
      .Name("EingangDrop")
      .Placeholder("Eingang durch...")
      .DataTextField("WSText")
      .DataValueField("ID")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { ng_model="Modell.EingangDurch" })
      .Filter("contains")
      .AutoBind(true)
      .MinLength(3)
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetVersand", "UserApi");
          })
          .ServerFiltering(false);
      })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't bind the `change` event for the combobox.

Try something like this:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
              .Name("EingangDrop")
              .Placeholder("Eingang durch...")
              .DataTextField("WSText")
              .DataValueField("ID")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { ng_model="Modell.EingangDurch" })
              .Filter("contains")
              .AutoBind(false)
              .MinLength(3)
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("GetVersand", "UserApi");
                  })
                  .ServerFiltering(false);
              })
             .Events(e =>
             {
                e.Change("onChange");
             })
        )
```

And a `javascript` function which will be called on the `changed` event like:

```
function onChange() {
        kendoConsole.log("event: change");
    }
```

You can see more events in action on their [page](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/events).